# Array contains() without case sensitive lookup?

Tags: java, arrays

Can I somehow tell the array.contains() method to not make the lookup case sensitive?

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList(
  "one", Two", "tHRee"); //lots of entries (100+)

data.contains("three");
```

Comment: I guess you mean `List.contains()`

Comment: Convert everything to lowercase before inserting into `data` and before looking up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751455/arraylist-contains-case-sensitivity

Comment: If the values in list are unique you can use `TreeSet` with [case insensitive comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

Comment: @yaens that's .Net not Java.

Comment: The duplicate is for .NET not Java.. stop voting :X

Comment: Its not duplicate. Who should fix this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`contains` just check if an object is present in the List. So you can't do a case insensitive lookup here, because "three" is a different object than "Three".

A simple approach to solve this would be

```
public boolean containsCaseInsensitive(String s, List<String> l){
     for (String string : l){
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
            return true;
         }
     }
    return false;
  }
```

and then

```
containsCaseInsensitive("three", data);
```

Java 8+ version:

```
public boolean containsCaseInsensitive(String s, List<String> l){
        return l.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.equalsIgnoreCase(s));
    }
```

Comment: @membersound - how did you use equalsIgnoreCase for this scenario?

Comment: @KishanSolanki - I'm pretty sure it works. What does not work for you?

Answer (score -1):

it will require you to write your own `contains()` method.
pointers for custom `contains()`:

1. iterate over all the elements in the list.
2. compare the parameter string with all the values in
3. to make comparison case-insensitive be sure to apply any of toLowerCase or toUpperCase on BOTH parameter and the current element.

   List list;
       public boolean contains(String str){

   ```
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
          if(list.elementAt(i).toLowerCase().Equals(str.toLowerCase())) return true;
      }
   return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: Not an efficient answer.  You are converting `str` to lower case N times (once for each element of `list`), and you are converting each item of `list` to lower case every time you call this method.  If you are going to the trouble of writing your own method, just use `equalsIgnoreCase` and skip all of the allocations.