# Check if a Java Set contains a particular string, independent of case

Tags: java

I'm trying to test whether a set of strings contains a particular string, independent of case. For example, if mySet contained "john" xor "John" xor "JOHN" xor..., then

```
mySet.contains("john")
```

(or something similar) should return true.

Comment: Similar question: [ArrayList contains case sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8751455/142162)

Comment: I mean, the answer is: you can't if you're using `.contains()`. Sets use hashing. You'd have to iterate through the set and compare each entry.

Comment: @BrianRoach, right, simply using `contains()` doesn't work. I'm looking for something that has similar behavior as that method, but case insensitive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When constructing the set, use a sorted set with a case insensitive comparator.  For example:

```
Set<String> s = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
s.addAll(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));

//Returns true
System.out.println("Result: " + s.contains("One"));
```