# better way to avoid multiple OR statements in java if condition

Tags: java

Is there any better way to avoid multiple `OR` statements in `if` condition?
I have `if` with more than 8 strings in `OR` statements.

```
if(type.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherString1) ||   
   type.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherString2) ||   
   type.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherString3)){
    return true;
}
```

Looking for better approach to write `if` with multiple `OR` statements or how to avoid

Comment: What is "better"? More readable? Faster? Some other criteria?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158018/check-if-a-java-set-contains-a-particular-string-independent-of-case

Answer (score 7):

Simply enough, you can build a Set with the different values to test **in lower case** (using `toLowerCase()` if needed).

Then, change your statement to:

```
if (<set_name>.contains(type.toLowerCase()))
```

The interest is also that you add some semantic to your code. Your set will have a name, something functionally suited for your case (`allowedUserTypes`, `elementTypesToProcess` or whatever) and can be set somewhere useful for reuse, if relevant.

Comment: Don't forget that when building the `Set`, it should be populated with lowercase values too =)

Comment: Yeah, I wrote "with the different values to test in lower case". I'll put it in bold ^^.

Answer (score 3):

A way to avoid using a chain of `if` statements or many `||` operators 
 could be a `switch`.

To achieve the same outcome using a `switch`, this would look like :

```
switch(type){
  case anotherString1:
  case anotherString2:
  case anotherString3:
    return true;
}
```

notice that each of these cases fall through on eachother, meaning if any of these cases are hit we will `return true`.

keep in mind this assumes case is already ignored.

more information on `switch` here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-in-switch-case-in-java/

Comment: It is worth noting that when using variables as cases in switch statements, they have to be non-mutable. [They must be constants](https://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/can-i-use-variables-in-case-clauses-in-the-switch-statement/113).

Answer (score 1):

Supose to manage to get all your `otherString1`, `otherString2`, and `otherString3` on a list called `List<String> otherStrings`, then you could take advantage of the  `contains()` method. But this wouldn't solve all your problems, as you want to ignore the case.

So, let's use streams, as [this other SO answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435424/1305745):

```
List<String> otherStrings = ...;

boolean containsType = otherStrings.stream()
    .anyMatch(otherString-> otherString.equalsIgnoreCase(type));
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to include any number of `otherString`s in the `List` without having to change the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If all your conditions try to match for a given string, you could have a list of strings and use [contains (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("type1", "type2",......);

if (type != null) {
    if (list.contains(type.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams you could do something like:

```
return  Stream.of(anotherString1,anotherString2,anotherString3)
              .anyMatch(e->e.equalsIgnoreCase(type));
```

which allows you to omit even the if statement.

Comment: Beware that omitting the if statement actually changes the semantics. In the OP example, you don't know what happens if the condition is not met. Maybe other tests are performed and the method result might still be true!

Answer (score 0):

Since no state is involved, recommend you create a static method as follows.

```java
   public static boolean anyEqual(String arg, String... strs) {
      return Arrays.stream(strs).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(
            Collectors.toSet()).contains(arg.toLowerCase());
   }
```

Then you can call the method in either fashion below:

```java
      String[] strs = { "string1", "string2", "string3"
      };

      System.out.println(anyEqual("string2", strs));
      System.out.println(anyEqual("test", "test1", "test2", "test3"));
```